# Issue with at.js plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using `at.js` plugin, it works all fine, expect the moment when I use arrow keys up/down when the dropdown is shown. In this moment it focuses second list and the dropdown is hidden.

I know that the problem is that I used `JQuery` to navigate through list, but is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks in advance!

```js
var li = $('li.test');
      var liSelected;
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 40) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if (next.length > 0) {
              liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
              liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
          } else {
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
          }
        } else if (e.which === 38) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if (next.length > 0) {
              liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
              // liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
          } else {
            // liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
          }
        }
        $('li.selected .single-line').focus();
      });
  $('.single-line').atwho({
    at: "@",
    data:['Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4']
  })
```

```css
.atwho-view {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 18px;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    min-width: 120px;
    z-index: 11110 !important;
}

.atwho-view .atwho-header {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eaeff1;
    color: #6f8092;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.atwho-view .atwho-header .small {
    color: #6f8092;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.atwho-view .atwho-header:hover {
    cursor: default;
}

.atwho-view .cur {
    background: #3366FF;
    color: white;
}
.atwho-view .cur small {
    color: white;
}
.atwho-view strong {
    color: #3366FF;
}
.atwho-view .cur strong {
    color: white;
    font:bold;
}
.atwho-view ul {
    /* width: 100px; */
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.atwho-view ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* border-top: 1px solid #C8C8C8; */
}
.atwho-view small {
    font-size: smaller;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Caret.js/0.3.1/jquery.caret.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/at.js/1.5.0/js/jquery.atwho.min.js"></script>


<div id = 'main'>
<ul>
   <li class="test"><div id = 'n1' contenteditable=true class="single-line">Pres @ character</div></li>
   <li class="test"> <div id = 'n2' contenteditable=true class="single-line">Test</div></li>
   <li class="test"> <div id = 'n3' contenteditable=true class="single-line"> Content 3</div></li>
   <li class="test"> <div id = 'n4' contenteditable=true class="single-line"> Content 4</div></li>
</ul>
    
   

   
</div>
```

Comment: May i know what is the purpose of at.js ?

Comment: I don't get why you try to code the arrow behavior... Since the arrows are already usable in this [at.js demo](http://ichord.github.io/At.js/). **Then**, your `liSelected` is undefined (declared, but undefined). It gets defined by the else statement, wich will always be [`li.eq(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) (**your first li**) while adding the class «selected» to it.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, I need to navigate through list too :(

Comment: Ok... You want to navigate throught your editable lis... Not throught the at.js dropdown... I finally get it. There may be a way... But it's the dropdown that will not listen to arrows.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, I want to navigate through both of them :(

Comment: @BlackBurn027, here is a demo what at.js plugin does: http://ichord.github.io/At.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help to understant what you code does...
Maybe you tought it was doing something else.
See comments in code.

```
var li = $('li.test');
var liSelected;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (liSelected) {                                   // Undefined on first keydown, Always equals li.eq[0] rest of the time.
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if (next.length > 0) {                          // Will NEVER be more than zero since .next selects one element.
            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected'); // So you define it to your first li here too.
            }
        } else {
        liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');         // liSelected is defined here on first keydown only.
        }                                                   // li.eq[0] is you first li, the one with id = 'n1'
    } else if (e.which === 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (liSelected) {                                   // Exact same comments as above for this part.
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if (next.length > 0) {
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
            // liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
        // liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
    }
    $('li.selected .single-line').focus();
});
```

Like I said in comments, the arrows are already usable with [at.js](http://ichord.github.io/At.js/).
As `liSelected` is undefined the if condition result in `false`.
Read on [`.eq() here`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

**2nd EDIT**
-------------------

**Here is something working.**

```
$(".single-line").on("focus", function () {
    $(".single-line").removeClass("selected"); // Clear all other "selected" class
    $(this).addClass("selected"); // Add "selected" class on focus... And on the editable div instead of on a li
});

var triggers = ["@", ":"];

$(".single-line").keydown(function (e) {

    console.log(e.which); // usefull console.log
    var current = $(this);
    var opened = current.find(".atwho-query");

    var flag = !!$.inArray(opened.html(), triggers);

    if (!flag) {
        console.log("query openned");
    } else {
        console.log("query closed");
        if (e.which === 40) { // Arrow down
            console.log("arrow down");
            current.parent().next().children(".single-line").focus(); // Set focus on next li.

        }
        if (e.which === 38) { // Arrow up
            console.log("arrow up");
            current.parent().prev().children(".single-line").focus(); // Set previous on next li.
        }
    }

});

// This was your code
$('.single-line').atwho({
    at : "@",
    data : ['Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4']
})
```

[example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/40eemy84/1/)

Comment: If I make another JQuery function for this, do you think I can achieve what I'm asking for?

Comment: Notice that I just re-edited for missing `.` and `)`... Looks ok now.

Comment: Thanks, but there are some errors, it cannot find the variable name liSelected

Comment: Hold on... I'm downloading it to test.

Comment: I voted your answer too, thank you so much for trying to help!! I appreciate :)

Comment: Thanks... I worked on it and I think I got it perfect. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Wow, you did an amazing job!! :)

Comment: Jus made one last improvement... Since other characters may trigger the dropdown in the future ;) I added an array.

Comment: Wow, very good, cus I need to trigger even in '#' character. Many thanks to you! Life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

Use At.js [events](https://github.com/ichord/At.js/wiki/Events) like this:

```
var isOpenAt = false;
$('.single-line').atwho({
    at : "@",
    data : ['Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4']
}).on("shown.atwho", function (event, flag, query) {
    isOpenAt = true;
}).on("hidden.atwho", function (event, flag, query) {
    isOpenAt = false;
});
```

This is not the best solution, but this working.

[example on jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Coddwrench/40eemy84/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much!! I really appreciated :)

Comment: Can we open @list from js using button click function?

Comment: @yasir_mughal, This functionality is not available, there is only`.atwho("hide")` but no `.atwho("show")` see [At.js API](https://github.com/ichord/At.js/wiki/APIs)

Comment: Have any idea how we can achieve this?

Comment: @yasir_mughal, nope, but you can ask a question.